New Dimension in RunReportRequest Reduces Results in Google Analytics (GA4) Python Data API
The behaviour I’m looking to understand (and ideally resolve) has to do with generating custom reports with a new companyId dimension created last week.
I notice that with the code below, when I uncomment the companyId dimension, the number of results returned are reduced significantly. To be specific, results are limited to the past 2 months of data rather than the full specified dateRange. All CompanyId results within the 2 months are set to (not set), which is to be expected, although I do not understand why this pattern doesn’t continue further back in time
It doesn’t appear that I am hitting any property_quotas at the moment either, according to the response.
Moreover, if I set the DateRange to a smaller interval from before two months ago, no results are returned whatsoever. It seems that whenever the companyID dimension is set, it is not possible to retrieve data from over two months ago. Why is this the case, and is there a way to resolve this?
RunReportRequest(
            property=f"properties/{GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID}",
            return_property_quota=True,
            dimensions=[
                Dimension(name="date"),
                Dimension(name="customEvent:itemId”),
                # Dimension(name="customEvent:companyId), # Uncommenting causes problem
            ],
            metrics=[
                Metric(name="eventCount"),
            ],
            date_ranges=[
                DateRange(start_date='2024-03-25’, end_date='2024-09-25’),
            ]
        ) 


If you add limit=250000 to your query do you get all of the data? I presume when you say the results are reduced you mean the date range is reduced and not the number of rows returned.
Data from the API is paginated with a default of 10,000 rows and a max of 250,000 rows. For more than 250,000 rows you'll have to also set an offset parameter and run the query again.
You can find details here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport#:~:text=The%20number%20of%20rows%20to,how%20many%20you%20ask%20for.
RunReportRequest(
            property=f"properties/{GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID}",
            return_property_quota=True,
            dimensions=[
                Dimension(name="date"),
                Dimension(name="customEvent:itemId”),
                # Dimension(name="customEvent:companyId), # Uncommenting causes problem
            ],
            metrics=[
                Metric(name="eventCount"),
            ],
            date_ranges=[
                DateRange(start_date='2024-03-25’, end_date='2024-09-25’),
            ],
            limit=250000
        ) 

